# How do I use a regular expression in JavaScript to see if a string begins with a period?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expressions.

The following code works as expected, printing first "true" and then "false", the backslash in front of the period escaping it:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\./);
document.write(pattern.test("."));
document.write(pattern.test("a"));
```

But why does the following print "false":

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/\b\./);
document.write(pattern.test("."));
```

The period is, after all, at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to try using `^` -

```
/^\./
```

If you have

```
/\b\./
```

it matches the `.`'s  in `Hello. How are you.`

Comment: I think I get it now. I just read a description of the word/non-word character distinction, and I'm guessing a string needs to begin with a word character for \b to think of it as a word.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because to have a word break, you first need to have a word.

Using a `\b`, this would work:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/a\b\./);
document.write(pattern.test("a."));
```

If all you're doing is testing the first character, you can do it without a regex if you'd like.

```
".".charAt(0) === "."
```